# @EnableSpringHttpSession with apache ignite

Tags: ignite, httpsession, spring-session

I'm using apache ignite for save session.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSpringHttpSession
public class IgniteSessionConfiguration {

    /**
     * Max inactive interval in seconds
     */
    @Value("${spring.session.ignite.defaultMaxInactiveInterval:#{null}}")
    private Integer maxInactiveInterval;

    @Bean
    public SessionRepository<ExpiringSession> sessionRepository(@NonNull Ignite ignite,
                                                                @NonNull CacheConfiguration<String, ExpiringSession> sessionCacheConfiguration) {
        val sessionCache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(sessionCacheConfiguration);
        val mappedSessionCache = new CacheMapAdapter<String, ExpiringSession>(sessionCache);
        val sessionRepository = new MapSessionRepository(mappedSessionCache);
        Optional.ofNullable(maxInactiveInterval)
                .ifPresent(sessionRepository::setDefaultMaxInactiveInterval);
        return sessionRepository;
    }
}
```

it works fine save ignite server but not expired.
So i found this comment at 'org.springframework.session.config.annotation.web.http.SpringHttpSessionConfiguration'

```
SessionEventHttpSessionListenerAdapter - is responsible for translating Spring
 * Session events into HttpSessionEvent. In order for it to work, the implementation of
 * SessionRepository you provide must support {@link SessionCreatedEvent} and
 * {@link SessionDestroyedEvent}.
```

I don't know how to SessionRepository support those SessionDestroyedEvent 
Please help me..

Thank you

Comment: CacheMapAdapter is some third party component, not a part of Apache Ignite, so I genuinely don't know how it is supposed to work.

Comment: I made a CacheMapAdapter.java implements Map class..

Comment: Well, good for you, but does it remove keys when they are expired?

Comment: yes, I configured that provide SessionDestroyedEvent but I dont know how